# Source not available during model and database syc in MySQL work Bench

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update a table and sync it with the source but the source isnt available as you can see in the screen shot

[image]

and the script is

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DAHMS`.`Answers` (
  `aid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `qid` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `sid` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `answer` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Answers_Session1_idx` (`sid` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Answers_Questions1_idx` (`qid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Answers_Session1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid` )
    REFERENCES `DAHMS`.`Session` (`sid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Answers_Questions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`qid` )
    REFERENCES `DAHMS`.`Questions` (`qid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: The question is why m getting "Source not available" though i never removed it and in case if i did it should still generate a new table for "Answers"

Comment: That's what "Next" will do, update the "Source". You probably did not have that table created previously. (or the script that you thought that created it, had an aerror.)